# ERROR: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, build

I have problem with build project in android-studio from https://github.com/Samsung/microbit.

I imported repository by git, but while build gradle project from in android-studio I have error:

```
ERROR: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71.
```

I am not sure how I can change version 1.2.72 to other version.

Edit:

Solution:

I added         `mavenCentral()` to

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: I had `jcentral` instead of `mavenCentral` in some old code. It helped me to use `mavenCentral`.

Comment: I meant `jCenter`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is no need to use that as you can use kotlin-stdlib directly.

Try this:

In your app level `build.gradle` file, under dependencies section:

```
dependencies{
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.41"
}
```

Comment: Thank, but when I used this suggestion added in app/build.gradle suddenly occurred for project. I am not sure where is these settings.

Comment: I couldn't understand you!

Comment: I don't understand where I should set this setting, becouse i have 4 files "gradle.build"

Comment: I changed this settings in main directory into build.gradle, but suddenly I have problem "ERROR: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71."  after "sync project with gradle files". Will you try setup this project?

Comment: @MartinInf1n1ty This is supposed to be added in the actual app directory's build.gradle file. Not in the root project's gradle file.